# How to check if, elif, else conditions at the same time in django template

Tags: python, django

I have 3 category in category field. I want to check it in django template and assign appropirte urls for 3 distinct category.

I tried:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
        {% if entry.category == 1 %}
        <a href="{% url 'member:person-list' %}"><li>{{ entry.category }}</li></a>
        {% elif entry.category == 2 %}          
        <a href="{% url 'member:execomember-list' %}"><li>{{ entry.category}}</li></a>
         {% else %}
         <a href="{% url 'member:lifemember-list' %}"><li>{{ entry.category}}</li></a>
        {% endif %}
{% empty %}
    <li>No recent entries</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But I know python only check first matching condition with if. Therefore it gave only one desired result. How do I get all three entries with their correct links?

**Edit:**

Though python only check first matching if condition, when use elif within for loop it check each condition until endfor loop. Therefore my answer below worked fine.

Comment: What? This isn't clear at all. Each `entry.category` can only match one of the conditions at a time. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Very unclear, sorry. `But I know python only check first matching condition with if` what do you expect ?

Comment: I am expecting output of all three categories. Since 3 categories are distinct and every one has a separate list. So I want to get name of all 3 categories with their links to get correct lists. And this list will get from their urls. I hope it will clear you

Comment: Not really, no. Each individual item in `entries` is checked against your conditions. And each item can only match one of those conditions.

Comment: `I am expecting output of all three categories.` then check your entries and see why only category 1 is there.

Comment: Sorry @Daniel , I have got my working answer. I posted my answer now.

Comment: Before downvote me, please see my answer and django shell code and try it in your django shell to check whether it is wrong or not given correct output.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is my working answers:

```
   {% for entry in entries %}
        {% if entry.category == 'General Member' %}
        <a href="{% url 'member:person-list' %}"><li>{{ entry.category }}</li></a>
    {% elif entry.category == 'Executive Committee Member' %}
        <a href="{% url 'member:execomember-list' %}"><li>{{ entry.category}}</li></a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'member:person-list' %}"><li>{{ entry.category}}</li></a>
        {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
        <li>No recent entries</li>
  {% endfor %}
```

Webpage view of output:

[image]

For more clarifications, I check my code with the django shell. See the snippet of my shell:

[image]

Even I change the order of if conditions, result remain the same. See my shell code with output:

[image]

Do you see any wrong with my codes? Its fully comply with the python conditions and gives expected results. Anybody can check it on their django shell.

Comment: Still don't get what you are trying to do.

Comment: So this in fact had nothing at all to do with Python "only checking first matching condition", but the fact that you were comparing strings with integers.

Comment: I posted a picture of my output and explanation to my answers. Whatever it, it gives me correct output for all 3 categories.

Comment: Before downvote me, try my django shell code in your django shell to check whether it works or not and indicate me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @ohid The point is that you are using for. Each iteration, a separate branch is selected. This is not strange.

Comment: Django template sytax is very tedious and hard to use. Garbage...

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to associate each entry to a url depending on the category it belongs among the 3 categories. you can have this refactored in your `Entry` model in order to minimize logic in templates like:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    category = ...

    def get_entry_url(self):
        if self.category == 'General Member':
            return reverse for the url 'member:person-list'

        elif self.category == 'Executive Committee Member':
            return reverse for the url 'member:execomember-list'

        else:
            return reverse for the url 'member:person-list'
```

Then in template:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
     <a href="{{ entry.get_entry_url }}"><li>{{ entry.category }}</li></a>
{% empty %}
    <li>No recent entries</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It could be another approach. Does it give me better performance than mine answers? It needs two places to use logic: both model and template whereas mine only one places i.e. template with I think less code.

Comment: Assuming in one of your views, you perform some logic and you need an entry's url to redirect to, you will only do `entry.get_entry_url()` as opposed to writing another `if...else` statement all over the codebase whenever you want to get an entry url. So this is not just another method, but a refactor and reducing much logic in templates which is a good practice.

Comment: Actually I used it in a inclusion tag