# Can't get a combination of if and elif to work in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two variables, `date1` and `date2`, both DateField. Here's what I'm trying to write:

- if `date1` and `date2` have values, display "Datation évaluée entre `date1` et `date2`".
- if `date1` have value but not `date2`, display "Datation évaluée vers `date1`".
- if `date2` have value but not `date1`, display "Datation évaluée vers `date2`".
- if neither `date1` nor `date2` have values, don't display anything.

Here is my code:

```
{% if 'date1' and 'date2' %}  
    Datation évaluée entre {{ object.date1 }} et {{ object.date2 }}.  
{% elif not 'date1' %}  
    Datation évaluée vers {{ object.date2 }}.  
{% elif not 'date2' %}  
    Datation évaluée vers {{ object.date1 }}.  
{% elif not 'date1' or 'date2' %}  
    Datation inconnue.
```

The first condition appears indeed, but not the others. When there's a value only on one side, I get "Datation évaluée entre `value1` et None.", and when there are no values, I get "Datation évaluée entre None et None."

Any ideas what's wrong in the code?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 'date1' is a string and not variable like it should be object.date1 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#the-django-template-language

Comment: And `not object.date1` is not sufficient to know if there is an `object.date2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if, elif, else conditions at the same time in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247352/how-to-check-if-elif-else-conditions-at-the-same-time-in-django-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the truthiness of the *strings* `'date1'` and `'date2'`, and a non-empty string always has truthiness `True`. You should check the items of the object.

Furthermore by checking `not object.date1`, we do not know if `object.date2` is given. We thus should check if `object.date2` has truthiness `True`:

```
{% if object.date1 and object.date2 %}
    Datation évaluée entre {{ object.date1 }} et {{ object.date2 }}.  
{% elif object.date2 %}  
    Datation évaluée vers {{ object.date2 }}.  
{% elif object.date1 %}
    Datation évaluée vers {{ object.date1 }}.  
{% else %}  
    Datation inconnue.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks for the details and explanation.